# How do I solve: Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackground...'

Tags: xcode, image, swift

Using Swift 1.2 how do I solve this? Thanks for your help in advance!

Code:

```
resultsImageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                cell.profileImg.image = image
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The function `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` is not Cocoa framework code. Is that Parse? If so you should add that to your question title, and add that tag as well. Also, what do you mean "How do I solve this?" What are you solving? You posted code, but not an explanation of how it doesn't meet your needs. Is it giving you a compiler error? Crashing when you run it? Running but not giving you the results you expect? You need to be very clear with what's going on if you want help.

Comment: Problem I have is I am running Swift 1.2 and with the above Code I run into the following error message: "cannot invoke: GetDayaInBackground...". Sorry for being confusing. I tried uploading an image but don't have quiet enough points yet to do so. If this still won't help I'll post the complete thing again from, just on the run right now :) thanks for your quick reply!!

Comment: You **still** didn't' provide enough information. Where is the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` function defined? (in what class?) What is the definition of that function? What is the complete, exact error message you are getting? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error?